# Applet and servlet session management

Tags: servlets, applet

When we communicate with a servlet to applet how can we ensure that session information is preserved?

That is, how can we manage cookies in applet servlet connection?

Comment: What kind of "applet servlet connection" are you talking about? Does the Servlet generate the HTML page that contains the applet, or do you create a HTTP connection to the servlet from the applet?

Comment: we are creating HTTP connection to connect servlet and applet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an API like `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient` https://hc.apache.org and use the HttpClient's CookieStore to set cookies to the request and read them from the reponse. Afterward you have to store the Cookie somewhere in your applet (see `getSessionCookie()` and `setSessionCookie()` method stubs):

```
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
public class Connector {

  private Cookie getSessionCookie() { /* TODO get cookie from some store (local session, DB, whatever) */ } 
  private void setSessionCookie(Cookie sessionCookie) { /* TODO set cookie to some store (local session, DB, whatever) */ } 


  private void connect() {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    Cookie sessionCookie = getSessionCookie();
    if (sessionCookie != null) {
      client.getCookieStore().addCookie(jsessionidCookie);
    }
    client.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy());

    // create a GET request to your Servlet in get()
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://example.com/your/servlet");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if (statusCode == 200) {
      sessionCookie = getJsessionidCookie(client.getCookieStore().getCookies());
      // update session cookie
      setSessionCookie(sessionCookie);
    }
  }
  private Cookie getJsessionidCookie(List<Cookie> cookies) {
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
      if (cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")) {
        return cookie;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```